# Doctrine Many-To-Many, Self-referencing weird behavior (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am having trouble with Doctrine Many-To-Many, Self-referencing [doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing)

Following the example in the docs:

```
<entity
    name="Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\Usersss"
    table="usersss"
    >

    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
        <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
    </id>

    <many-to-many field="myFriends" target-entity="Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\Usersss" inversedBy="friendsWithMe">
        <join-table name="friends">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column id="user_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column id="friend_user_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>

    <many-to-many field="friendsWithMe" target-entity="Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\Usersss" mappedBy="myFriends"/>
</entity>
```

Symfony2 should generate something like that (as it is written in the documentation)

```
CREATE TABLE usersss (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE friends (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    friend_user_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, friend_user_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE friends ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(id);
ALTER TABLE friends ADD FOREIGN KEY (friend_user_id) REFERENCES User(id);
```

but Symfony2 try to generate this:

```
CREATE TABLE usersss (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE friends (usersss_id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(usersss_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE usersss_usersss (usersss_source INT NOT NULL, usersss_target INT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_A8965F1863AC54F9 (usersss_source), INDEX IDX_A8965F187A490476 (usersss_target), PRIMARY KEY(usersss_source, usersss_target)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE friends ADD CONSTRAINT FK_21EE7069A764047 FOREIGN KEY (usersss_id) REFERENCES usersss (id);
ALTER TABLE usersss_usersss ADD CONSTRAINT FK_A8965F1863AC54F9 FOREIGN KEY (usersss_source) REFERENCES usersss (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE usersss_usersss ADD CONSTRAINT FK_A8965F187A490476 FOREIGN KEY (usersss_target) REFERENCES usersss (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

if I'll change inversedBy to inversed-by and mappedBy to mapped-by, mysql looks like

```
CREATE TABLE usersss (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE friends (usersss_id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(usersss_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE friends ADD CONSTRAINT FK_21EE7069A764047 FOREIGN KEY (usersss_id) REFERENCES usersss (id);
```

and this is still not looks like in documentation example

I can't understand why I get so weird behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Actually I found the problem: since you are in XML, you need to use "inversed-by" instead of "inversedBy" and "mapped-by" instead of "mappedBy".

**EDIT 2:** Also, replace "id" by "name" in your join-column.

Comment: Thanks for help! But I got the error "The table with name 'friends' already exists."

Comment: Edited my answer, my first solution was definetely not relevant. :)

Comment: I tried this too, but it still not work properly. I added result to my question

Comment: Edited again. Be really careful about mapping definition attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything works as it should.